# group text chat in as3 using flash media server?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have implemented simple text chat using fms and php but now i want to implement the group chat whoever come to online should be able to text each other can anyone help me implement this.

```
private function sendMessage(e:MouseEvent=null):void 
        {

            if (_message.message_box.input_txt.text=="Message..."||_message.message_box.input_txt.text == "")
                        {
                            //_message.message_box.input_txt.text = "";
                            UserInterface.getViewport().updateStatus("Please enter Text");
                        }

                else{       
            var msg:String = ApplicationShell.userName + ':' + _message.message_box.input_txt.text + '\n';

            _message.message_box.history_txt.text += msg;
            _message.message_box.input_txt.text = "";
            ApplicationShell.chatServer.post('<font color="#' + color + '">' + msg + '</font>');
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you develop your application for one to one using FMS and Flash client. Then its very simple to extend froup chat. you have to define only one instance of the your FMS for your application at the time of connecting FMS vis NetConnection api. and you have to give same instance default name to the all user .. you can develop it. and you have brodcast your message to the FMS and FMS inform all connected user your brodcasted message. .....

[Click Here for Example](http://thanksmister.com/2006/09/05/flex-flash-media-server-text-chat/)

[Another Example](http://robsilverton.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/fms-simple-chat-example-in-flex/)